# Azure Media Services -- Create Live Output and Streaming Locator with Python SDK

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-media-services, azure-sdk-python

I am working on a project that uses the Azure Media Services Python SDK (v3). I have the following code which creates a live output and a streaming locator once the associated live event is running:

```
# Step 2: create a live output (used to reference the manifest file)
live_outputs = self.__media_services.live_outputs
config_data_live_output = LiveOutput(asset_name=live_output_name, archive_window_length=timedelta(minutes=30))
output = live_outputs.create(StreamHandlerAzureMS.RESOUCE_GROUP_NAME, StreamHandlerAzureMS.ACCOUNT_NAME, live_event_name, live_output_name, config_data_live_output)

# Step 3: get a streaming locator (the ID of the locator is used in the URL)
locators = self.__media_services.streaming_locators
config_data_streaming_locator = StreamingLocator(asset_name=locator_name)
locator = locators.create(StreamHandlerAzureMS.RESOUCE_GROUP_NAME, StreamHandlerAzureMS.ACCOUNT_NAME, locator_name, config_data_streaming_locator)
```

`self.__media_services` is an object of type `AzureMediaServices`. When I run the code above, I receive the following exception:

```
azure.mgmt.media.models._models_py3.ApiErrorException: (ResourceNotFound) Live Output asset was not found.
```

**Question:** Why is Azure Media Services throwing this error with an operation that creates a resource? How can I resolve this issue?

Note that I have managed to authenticate the SDK to Azure Media Services using a service principal and that I can successfully push video to the live event using ffmpeg.

Comment: Just checking, did you create the asset - "live_output_name" before creating the Live Output?

Comment: @johndeu I did not. Is an asset a different concept from creating a resource itself?

Comment: See answer below, also note - I see an issue in your Streaming Locator create. 
StreamingLocator(asset_name=locator_name)

That asset name should be the same one used for the Live Output. It's the "tape" name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you take a quick look at the flow of a live event in this tutorial, which unfortunately is in .NET. We are still working on updating Python samples.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/stream-live-tutorial-with-api

But it should help with the issue. The first issue I see is that it's likely you did not create the Asset for the Live output to record into.

You can think of Live Outputs as "tape recorder" machines, and the Assets at the tapes.  They are locations in your storage account that the tape recorder is going to write to.

So after you have the Live Event running, you can have up to 3 of these "tape recorders" operating and writing to 3 different "tapes" (Assets) in storage.

1. Create an empty Asset
2. Create a live output and point it to that Asset
3. get the streaming locator for that Asset - so you can watch the tape. Notice that you are creating the streaming locator on the asset you created in step 1.  Think of it as "I want to watch this tape" and not "I want to watch this tape recorder".